# Second Box-Shadow Showing up in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I'm relatively new to coding and I'm working on this as homework for my CS195 (HTML/CSS) class. I'm trying to get both of the layouts to look the same in both browsers, but I can't figure out where my coding is wrong for Chrome. I'm using SublimeText3 if that helps at all.

(Ignore the navigation bar, I haven't fixed that yet either.)

I've tried adjusting the webkit box size and the moz box size, but I'm not sure what else to do because it affects the IE version of the website, but doesn't get rid of the secondary box on Chrome...

Code I'm using for the boxes:

```
.box {
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y:auto;
    height: 200px;
    width: 565px;
    background: rgb(255,255,255);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.50) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 20px;
    opacity: 0.85;
}

.box2 {
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y:auto;
    left: 20%;
    height: 545px;
    width: 650px;
    background: rgb(255,255,255);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.50) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 20px;
    opacity: 0.85;
}

.box3 {
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y:auto;
    height: 220px;
    width: 400px;
    background: rgb(255,255,255);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.50) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 20px;
    opacity: 0.85;
}

.box4 {
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y:auto;
    height: 220px;
    width: 400px;
    background: rgb(255,255,255);
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.50) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 20px;
    opacity: 0.85;
}
```

[Chrome results](https://prnt.sc/nncsxw)

[IE results](https://prnt.sc/nnctj6)

[This is one of the resources I tried](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-shadow/) - the first part, where it says:

```
.shadow {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;  /* Safari 3-4, iOS 4.0.2 - 4.2, Android 2.3+ */
  -moz-box-shadow:    3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;  /* Firefox 3.5 - 3.6 */
  box-shadow:         3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;  /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Firefox 4+, Chrome 6+, iOS 5 */
}
```

Any help would be really, really appreciated.  It's for my final.  Thanks!

Comment: I made a demo that using your code to display a box. It looks the same in chrome and IE.  I think the other parts of your code affect the display of the box. Could you share the other codes(HTML codes & CSS codes) related to the boxes for finding the issue?

Comment: I'm certain it's other parts of my code, just not sure where exactly.  I was thinking the same thing.  I posted all of it into a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hyrulianprince/kxgqm7t6/2/) (but it won't run because it's all on my computer, not published online).  It's the only thing I could think of to help.  Thank you, by the way!  I've been stuck on this for a while now and it's bothering me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduce a part of your code you provided in jsfiddle and I found that if we drop `padding: 20px;` in `<div> #main, #recent, #favs, #followus` in css, the second box-shadow will disappear in Chrome.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Yu!  That worked and I feel dumb for not triple checking that, haha.  Really, thank you, I've been stuck on that for a week or so now!